# rendering scene using multithreading in opengles

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am developing a iphone game I am using multi threading for drawing multiple objects on screen ,But I am not clear that how can render a specific scene using all these threads ,should I use same FOB in all threads to update the scene or is there any other technique for rendering the scene using multiple threads .please help 
Code given below(Placed in separate thread) gives the bad acces

```
-(void)drawBricks1{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

//glViewport(0, 0,backingWidth, backingHeight);
Image *ii=[[Image alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"s_2.png"]];  
[ii renderAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) centerOfImage:YES];
// Clear screen
//glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);


[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
[pool release];

}// end of the drawb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framebuffer is a multually exlusive resource. If you'd split the framebuffer into distinct areas parallel access was possible. However in the usual case of rendering with OpenGL you access a windows framebuffer as a whole. Thus each thread must lock access to the framebuffer -- this is done by the driver. This locking causes huge overhead, causing a severe performance hit. Or in a few words: OpenGL and multithreading don't mix (well).

Any why do you care anyway? The GPU will parallelize the rendering process internally, so there's absolutely no need for multithreaded access. Especially on a device like the iPhone/iPad which GPU is not designed for multithreaded access (even if it was to distinct framebuffers).

Comment: but issue is that ,I am doing calculations regarding to games in same main thread and also different rendering methods in that thread,due to this i am felling some sort of delay in iphone3 but it works fine in iphone4 :).

Comment: As long as you keep all OpenGL operations in one thread, you can create as many threads you like. Problems begin, if multiple threads access one OpenGL context at the same time.

Comment: but then issue I mentioned is that I am not able to combine the scene from all these threads,for example if ships are moving in one thread and player is moving an other thread ,how to combine these to make one scene

Comment: By reading from all the required variables from the OpenGL thread. Threads are not isolated from each other, so you can just read stuff from other threads. However you must lock things properly of course. Anyway: You shouldn't spawn a thread for each object on the screen. Technically you should have no more threads running than there are CPU cores. Just process all those elements in a loop.